# AdobeFlashCS6 Actionscript3 JSON: Exported SWF and HTML banner don't show JSON information

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I have a *.swf* banner that in adobe FlashCS6 plays fine,  but when I export it ( *.swf* and *.html*) the banner looses JSON information taken from online JSON file.

What am I doing wrong?

ActionScript Code:

```
play();
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var _jsonPath:String = yourURL;
function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.url = _jsonPath;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
    loader.load(request);
}    
init();  
function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    var jsonObject:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
    //JsonMan.decode(s:String):Object
    trace("loader.data: " + loader.data);
    trace(jsonObject[3].object.bets[0].title);
    if(i<10){
        country1.text = String(jsonObject[i].object.bets[0].title).toUpperCase();
        country2.text = String(jsonObject[i].object.bets[2].title).toUpperCase();
        country1_odds.htmlText = String("<b>"+ jsonObject[i].object.bets[0].odds + "</b>");
        country2_odds.htmlText = String("<b>"+jsonObject[i].object.bets[2].odds + "</b>");
        x_odds.htmlText = String("<b>"+jsonObject[i].object.bets[1].odds + "</b>");
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 
        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        } 

        today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;
        trace(today);

        obj_date.htmlText = String("<b>" + jsonObject[i].object.date + "</b>");
        i++;
        if(i==9){
            i=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

In Chrome console it says:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED cloudssl.my.phpcloud.com/super/contentScript.js 2. 
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) api.topsport.lt/crossdomain.xml. 
>   GET api.topsport.lt/crossdomain.xml 404 (Not Found) crossdomain.xml:1

In output I receive this text:

```
    `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`
`at TOPSPORT2_fla::MainTimeline/onLoaderComplete()`
`at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()`
`at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()`
`at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()`
    `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`
`at TOPSPORT2_fla::MainTimeline/onLoaderComplete()`
`at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()`
`at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()`
`at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()`
```

Comment: Do you even enter inside the `onLoaderComplete` function? If no - try adding SecurityError Event.

Comment: What do you mean by if I enter inside? I think I enter because it all works then used in adobe flash swf play, but then not in Flash, it don't show the requested info.

In chrome console it says:
    **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED       https://cloudssl.my.phpcloud.com/super/contentScript.js
2. 

    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://api.topsport.lt/crossdomain.xml. 
    GET http://api.topsport.lt/crossdomain.xml 404 (Not Found) crossdomain.xml:1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add listener for SecurityErrorEvent:

```
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
```

It will give you an error because you do not have a crossdomain policy file. Search Google for it - it's a simple xml file that you put on the root of your server. It helps Flash know that it can load resources from that location.

Comment: I've added **securityErrorEvent** and 
I don't receive the crossdomain error anymore, thanx :) . (the host of that link holder has put the **crossdomain.xml** file in his domain). But **swf** still doesn't show the information of the **JSON online database**. What could have caused this problem?

Comment: What does this line trace: `trace("loader.data: " + loader.data);`?

Comment: It traces the whole **JSON Database** info. It doesn't cause trouble - I used it to know if adobe flash decodes info from the database.(I already deleted this line).

Comment: Now in output I receive this text:
        `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`
 `at TOPSPORT2_fla::MainTimeline/onLoaderComplete()`
 `at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()`
 `at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()`
 `at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()`
        `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`
 `at TOPSPORT2_fla::MainTimeline/onLoaderComplete()`
 `at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()`
 `at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()`
 `at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()`

Comment: Well as long as it traces the JSON - everything from now on is in your hands :) You haven't parsed it properly maybe.. I think we've resolved this problem :) If you like - post new one..

Comment: Thank you very much. It all works just fine. It's very frustrating, than I only needed to clear the browser catche. You were very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets into a situation like this, always remember to clear the browser's catche, or test it on other browsers. It helped in my condition! The code was working all along.